# Flask: Include HTML in a return render_template() or redirect()

Tags: python, flask, sqlite

I have a login form that checks if the username and password given by the user returns a row or not in the database. If it does, then a session cookie is stored and user is sent back to the index page. If not, the user is sent back to the login page again.

Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?", (request.form['username'], request.form['password']))

data = cur.fetchone()[0]

# If given username and password returns a row, create the session
if data == 0:
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
else:
    session['username'] = request.form['username']
```

When the user is sent back to the login page again (`redirect(url_for('index'))`), I want to include a message on the login page saying that the given username or password is invalid.

I'm a bit lost on how to do this exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called Message Flashing. The full documentation is [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/flashing/), and it's done by adding the messages on the view side and then rendering them on template like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>My Application</title>
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
  {% if messages %}
    <ul class=flashes>
    {% for message in messages %}
      <li>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout `flash` at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/flashing/. That should do what you want. Just handle the flash messages in the template for `index`!